# Error while implementing MultiSelectListPreference

Tags: android, android-preferences, android-multiselectlistpreference

I tried to make small project using things which I learned on Google Scholarship on Udacity.
Unfortunately I have a bug with MultiSelectListPreference.

Code:
https://github.com/Slupik/temp10.06

Error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Process: CLASS_PATH, PID: 29964

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{CLASS_PATH/CLASS_PATH.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class (not found)MultiSelectListPreference

at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)

at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)

at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)

at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)

at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)

at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)

at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)

Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class (not found)MultiSelectListPreference

Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class (not found)MultiSelectListPreference

at android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceInflater.createItemFromTag(PreferenceInflater.java:297)

at android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceInflater.rInflate(PreferenceInflater.java:354)

at android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceInflater.inflate(PreferenceInflater.java:162)

at android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceInflater.inflate(PreferenceInflater.java:112)

at android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceManager.inflateFromResource(PreferenceManager.java:138)

at android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat.addPreferencesFromResource(PreferenceFragmentCompat.java:432)

at CLASS_PATH.SettingsFragment.onCreatePreferences(SettingsFragment.java:15)

at android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat.onCreate(PreferenceFragmentCompat.java:224)

at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2339)

at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1377)

at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1640)

at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1896)

at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:3673)

at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:111)

at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:338)

at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi14.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityApi14.java:39)

at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:67)

at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:780)

at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)

at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)

at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)

at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)

at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)

at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)

at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)

at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)

at CLASS_PATH.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:11)

at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)

at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)

at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)

at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)

at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    01-06 01:39:09.412 29964-29964/CLASS_PATH E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)

at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)

at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)

at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v7.preference.MultiSelectListPreference" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/CLASS_PATH-0NMXgK2MJ4k_VmRAgw2kqg==/base.apk",
zip file "/data/app/CLASS_PATH-0NMXgK2MJ4k_VmRAgw2kqg==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk",
zip file "/data/app/CLASS_PATH-0NMXgK2MJ4k_VmRAgw2kqg==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk",
zip file "/data/app/CLASS_PATH-0NMXgK2MJ4k_VmRAgw2kqg==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk",
zip file "/data/app/CLASS_PATH-0NMXgK2MJ4k_VmRAgw2kqg==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk",
zip file "/data/app/CLASS_PATH-0NMXgK2MJ4k_VmRAgw2kqg==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk",
zip file "/data/app/CLASS_PATH-0NMXgK2MJ4k_VmRAgw2kqg==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk",
zip file "/data/app/CLASS_PATH-0NMXgK2MJ4k_VmRAgw2kqg==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk",
zip file "/data/app/CLASS_PATH-0NMXgK2MJ4k_VmRAgw2kqg==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk",
zip file "/data/app/CLASS_PATH-0NMXgK2MJ4k_VmRAgw2kqg==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk",
zip file "/data/app/CLASS_PATH-0NMXgK2MJ4k_VmRAgw2kqg==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk",
zip file "/data/app/CLASS_PATH-0NMXgK2MJ4k_VmRAgw2kqg==/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/CLASS_PATH-0NMXgK2MJ4k_VmRAgw2kqg==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]

at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:93)

at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)

at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)

at android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceInflater.createItem(PreferenceInflater.java:228)

at android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceInflater.onCreateItem(PreferenceInflater.java:276)

at android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceInflater.createItemFromTag(PreferenceInflater.java:285)

... 38 more
```

The code is a sample code made by professional devs. I only added few lines in arrays.xml and pref_visualizer.xml

I already asked about this on dedicated forum but nobody can help me. So people at stackoverflow are my last hope

Comment: Did you add activity entry in manifest file.

Comment: Yes, I think so ;)
https://github.com/Slupik/temp10.06/blob/master/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
Without MultiSelectListPreference everything is ok

Comment: Got the same problem.